# why my iis urlrewrite rule is wrong here?

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

what I have is 
devoldname.mysite.net 
stagingoldname.mysite.net
oldname.mysite.net

and I want to do either a urlrewrite or urlredirect, so all traffic to above urls go to:
devnewname.mysite.net
stagingnewname.mysite.net
newname.mysite.net

I defined this iis rewrite rule

```
<rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="test" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="(.*)oldname.mysite.net" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="redirect" url="{C:1}newname.mysite.net" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

I was hoping that it will catch devoldname.mysite.net and redirect to devnewname.mysite.net

However, when accessing via this url: 
devoldname.mysite.net/admin/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fadmin%2fsamples2.aspx

I got this:
http://devoldname.mysite.net/devnewname.mysite.net?ReturnUrl=%2fadmin%2fsamples2.aspx

So somehow it appends both together and seems replaced login.aspx part, what I am doing wrongly?

What am I doing wrong? Can someone help?

Comment: Why don't you go through your DNS provider?  I had the same issue so I logged into GoDaddy and in Domain Settings I updated the "Forwarding" option.

Comment: the thing is that customer wants the old url to be replaced with the new url (like a 301 permanent redirect). I thought iis rewrite can do the work. maybe has to use some code

Answer (score 0):

You are very close.  I bet it would work if you redirected to the fully qualified URL. Try something like this:

```
     <rewrite>
        <rules>
          <rule name="test" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url=".*" />
            <conditions>
              <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="(.*)oldname.mysite.net" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="redirect" url="http://{C:1}newname.mysite.net" />
          </rule>
        </rules>
      </rewrite>
```